# Visual Studio 2012 installation hangs in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've just done a fresh install of Windows 8 and I'm now trying to install VS2012 but the installation always hangs at seemingly random points. I've tried reinstalling countless times, cleaning the registry but nothing seems to make a difference...

What could it be?

Comment: Can you post a log from your Event Viewer?

Comment: It takes a lot of time to install (20 mins in my case though mine was the Ultimate edition), so you probably just wait it out

Answer (score 0):

That's actually normal in VS 2012. You have to remember that a lot of the components of Visual Studio are very large. Some are large enough that they need to be downloaded separately as Visual Studio installs. If your installing the ultimate edition it might that much longer.